# Concatenar variable php

Tags: php

Deseo concatenar una variable, es decir, como en el ejemplo de abajo que la variable gastos se aumente al número. Un ejemplo seria: gastos1, gastos2, gastos3,etc hasta que termine el while.

```
$i=0;
        while ($listado=$c11->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $i++;
            $gastos="SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,SUM(saldo) as monto2,fiscal FROM ".nombre1." WHERE SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,1)='6' and fiscal='".$f."' and fecha>='".$fechaini."'and fecha<='".$fechafin."' and cod_subempresa=".$listado['id_proyecto']." and cod_subsub=".$listado['id_subproyecto']." and factura<>'CIERRES' GROUP BY substr(NCUENTA,1,7) ORDER BY cod_subempresa,cod_subsub,NCUENTA";
            $gastos.strval($i)=$dbh->prepare($gastos);
            $gastos.strval($i)->execute(); 
            print_r($list['id_proyecto']);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos lo que hace ese *curioso*  código? Quizá se pueda optimizar, nunca me ha gustado ejecutar consultas a la base de datos dentro de bucles, quien sabe, puede haber miles de filas y el servidor de base de datos puede terminar exhausto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución completa a la duda que tenía anterior es la siguiente:

```
            $gastos="SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,SUM(saldo) as monto2,fiscal FROM ".nombre1." WHERE SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,1)='6' and fiscal='".$f."' and fecha>='".$fechaini."'and fecha<='".$fechafin."' and cod_subempresa=0 and cod_subsub=0 and factura<>'CIERRES' GROUP BY substr(NCUENTA,1,7) ORDER BY NCUENTA";
        $gastos0=$dbh->prepare($gastos);
        $gastos0->execute(); 

        $i=0;
        while ($listado=$c11->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $i++;
            $gasto[$i]=0;
            ${"nombre".$i}=$listado['proyecto'];
            $gastos="SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,SUM(saldo) as monto2,fiscal FROM ".nombre1." WHERE SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,1)='6' and fiscal='".$f."' and fecha>='".$fechaini."'and fecha<='".$fechafin."' and cod_subempresa=".$listado['id_proyecto']." and cod_subsub=".$listado['id_subproyecto']." and factura<>'CIERRES' GROUP BY substr(NCUENTA,1,7) ORDER BY cod_subempresa,cod_subsub,NCUENTA";
            ${"gastos".$i}=$dbh->prepare($gastos);
            ${"gastos".$i}->execute(); 
            while ($datos=${"gastos".$i}->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $gasto[$i]=$datos;
            array_push($gasto[$i], ${"nombre".$i});
            print_r($gasto[$i]);
            }
        }
```

el código lo uso para hacer un reporte de estados financieros detallado por proyecto y por eso lo ocupaba en un array para llamarlo luego

Comment: Sería bueno explicar un poco más la solución, ¿te animas a darle a [edit] y hacerlo?